# Whats the best way of connecting these multiple coax cables?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am building a double cross antenna where I have to connect four different dipoles together like in the picture below. I'm somewhat new to this and I'm not sure what the best way of doing this is.

Soldering the center wires shouldn't be a problem but how do I properly connect the shields? Are there any fancy connectors for this? If no, do I just somehow solder the shields together or should I use an additional wire to connect them?

Of course in the end it should be sturdy and the additional noise should be minimal too.

[image: Diagram of connections]

Comment: With a junction box and coax plugs. Plenty available on the interweb.

Comment: good question for EE.SE